# How can I declare a function from another file in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function in a file:

```
function alertWin(title, message) {
   .......
   .......
}
```

In another typescript file I have:

```
function mvcOnFailure(message) {
    "use strict";
    alertWin("Internal Application Error", message);
}
```

I am getting an error saying "alertwin" does not exist in the current scope.

Is the way to solve this for me to define this function in another file and then reference that? If so then what would the definition look like?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this (assuming title and message are both supposed to be strings):

```
interface alertWinInterface{
    (title:string, message: string):any;
}

declare var alertWin: alertWinInterface;
```

You could put this in the same file, or put it in a separate ambient definitions file (.d.ts) which you import:

```
/// <reference path="myDefinitions.d.ts" />
```

Or, you could just import the other file that has the actual function definition, but you won't get static typing support.

Comment: I think both files are TypeScript files, so you don't need to create an additional definition, you just need to point to the existing TypeScript file.

Comment: @Sohnee: Yes, I suggested that at the end. It wasn't clear from the question whether or not that was what they wanted to do.

Answer (score 22):

This approach seems to work for me:

```
declare function alertWin(title: string, message: string) : void;
```

And as with Matt's solution you put it in a definition file and then reference it.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to tell the tools and compiler where to find your function, by adding a reference to the top of your file:

```
/// <reference path="fileWithFunction.ts" />
```

Additionally, all of your parameters are currently typed as `any`, you can type them explicitly if you wish.

```
function alertWin(title: string, message: string) : void {
   //.......
   //.......
}
```