# Anonymous Functions with parameters in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm trying to create an anonymous function in typescript with parameters I'm trying the following format:

```
(function ($, undefined) => {})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to create a definition file for an existing js libary called jQuery-total-storage.js

What is the proper format?

I'm new to Typescript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I declare a function from another file in Typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087573/how-can-i-declare-a-function-from-another-file-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really define an external function with a lambda expression - a lambda is an implementation not an interface. It can't be used to only express a contract, because it also expresses how that contract is implemented.

If you need to define an external function, you need to define one as part of an interface.

---

Looking at the jQuery Total Storage library, it seems to extend from the `jQuery` singleton. To extend from here, you must extend the `JQueryStatic` interface (as defined by [`DefininitelyTyped`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts)), adding the extended operations.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    totalStorage(key: string, value: any): void;
    totalStorage(key: string): any;
}
```

Interfaces are just strongly-typed declarations. In this case, it's adding type information to the external library.

To be clear: **you can only add type information, you can't change the signatures.**

Comment: Can this be an anonymous function of the interface?
IE:
interface JQueryTotalStorage extends JQuery {
                    ($, undefined): void;
    totalStorage:   (key, value, options) => any;
    setItem:        (key, value) => any;
    getItem:        (key) => any;
    getAll:         () => any;
}

($, undefined) => { bla bla

Comment: You can declare a function with no name in an interface, which makes instances of the interface act like a functional delegate. Looking at the actual library, I don't see what you would map to an anonymous delegate - they're all identified by names.