# Test component with "declare var"

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

In my angular2 app I have js file "connection.conf.js" with var:

```
var appTypeConf = "example-app";
```

Component uses the variable from "connection.conf.js":

```
declare var appTypeConf: string;

export class Component {
  public appType = appTypeConf;
}
```

it works corectly in my app, but when I test application with karma, 
I receive a error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: appTypeConf (line 9)
```

How to corectly declare a variable in the component spec file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13087573/2435473)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to add connection.conf.js path to files array in karma.conf.js

```
var files = [
  // ***
  'app/connection.conf.js'
]
```

Comment: That worked for me as well but I have to point out that the file containing the global variable has to be placed as the first item in the `files`array of `karma.conf.js`.

Comment: can you please paste here your code form karma.conf.js and test case how you have written please