# How to spy or reference an external js namespace in Angular 2 Test?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

declare var bootbox: any;
declare var $: any;

... other component code here
```

Notice that I have declared "bootbox" and "$" to the component. These are namespaces of the external libraries I am using in my angular app (jQuery and BootBox)

Now, I am using it similar to this: (in the component)

```
OnCreateClick(){
    bootbox.alert("create something");
    myService.createSomething();
}
```

And on my test:

```
describe('OnCreateClick', () => {
    it('should call createSomething on myService', async(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        var myService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService); 
        spyOn(myService, 'createSomething').and.returnValue(new Something());

        app.OnCreateClick();

        expect(myService.createSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

This is just a simple test to check if the createSomething() is called on myService. However, since "bootbox" is also called inside the component, the tests fails and gives this error on the test karma runner:

```
Failed: Uncaught : ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined
ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined
```

How to spy or reference an external js namespace in Angular 2 Test?

Comment: Can't you just do the same, being `declare var bootbox: any` ?

Comment: Hi, I did that but same error. I think it is referring as not defined in the component itself that is loaded and not on the tests. Since bootbox is loaded only when the browser is requesting the page? It's an external js file.

Comment: Then try adding your script (like you add it in your angular-cli file) to the karma conf file (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099179/test-component-with-declare-var) for more)

Comment: Man, that totally worked! Thanks a lot! Can you make this into a proper answer so I could accept. Thanks!

Comment: @Raven sorry, I can't take credit, it's a duplicate. Upvote the other post, and I'll mark this one as duplicate !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test component with "declare var"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099179/test-component-with-declare-var)

Comment: I see, still - thanks man