# How to stub a `declare var` for component in Angular Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner

We are using a library that requires that we 
`declare var LIBCONFIG` in our Angular component. LIBCONFIG is a member of the library that is. We use that var in `ngOnInit` to customize the behavior of the library.

When running our tests we get the following error as you might exect

```
Failed: LIBCONFIG is not defined
ReferenceError: LIBCONFIG is not defined
```

The variable is declared in a typescript file in a node_module.

I have tried the following based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099179/test-component-with-declare-var) to have Karma load this global variable from `karma.conf.js` so that the tests will not fail.

```
files: [
      ...,
      './node_modules/ng2-lib/src/libwithglobal.component.ts'
    ]
```

It seems like the file is being found as I'm not getting any karma warnings about the file not existing so it appears it is being loaded. What's the correct way to stub this variable for the component so the component can be built for the tests?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Hi @arunondeck, no I was not able to find a solution unfortunately. From what I recall we had to forgo that particular test since it was being such a pain. I'm sorry I don't have more specifics, been a while since I have used karma